# scrape tennis results including tournament for each match row

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape tennis matches results from [this website](http://www.tennisprediction.com/?year=2020&month=9&day=14)

The results table I want has the columns: `tournament_name   match_time   player_1   player_2   player_1_score   player_2_score`

This is an example

```
tournament_name      match_time   player_1           player_2               p1_set1   p2_set1
Roma / Italy         11:00        Krajinovic Filip   Auger Aliassime Felix  6         4
Iasi (IX) / Romania  10:00        Bourgue Mathias    Martineau Matteo       6         1
```

I can't associate each tournament name on the `id="main_tour"` with each row (one row is 2 `class="match"` or 2 `class="match1"`

I tried this code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

u = "http://www.tennisprediction.com/?year=2020&month=9&day=14"

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:76.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/76.0'}
session = requests.Session()
r = session.get(u, timeout=30, headers=headers)
# print(r.status_code)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

for table in soup.select('#main_tur'):
    tourn_value = [i.get_text(strip=True) for i in table.select('tr:nth-child(1)')][0].split('/')[0].strip()
    tourn_name = [i.get_text(strip=True) for i in table.select('tr td#main_tour')]
    row = [i.get_text(strip=True) for i in table.select('.match')]
    row2 = [i.get_text(strip=True) for i in table.select('.match1')]
    print(tourn_value, tourn_name)
```

Comment: What issue are you facing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this script to save the table to CSV in your format:

```
import requests 
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'http://www.tennisprediction.com/?year=2020&month=9&day=14'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

all_data = []
for t in soup.select('.main_time'):
    p1 = t.find_next(class_='main_player')
    p2 = p1.find_next(class_='main_player')
    tour = t.find_previous(id='main_tour')
    scores1 = {'player_1_set{}'.format(i): s for i, s in enumerate((tag.get_text(strip=True) for tag in t.parent.select('.main_res')), 1)}
    scores2 = {'player_2_set{}'.format(i): s for i, s in enumerate((tag.get_text(strip=True) for tag in t.parent.find_next_sibling().select('.main_res')), 1)}
    all_data.append({
        'tournament_name': ' / '.join( a.text for a in tour.select('a') ),
        'match_time': t.text,
        'player_1': p1.get_text(strip=True, separator=' '),
        'player_2': p2.get_text(strip=True, separator=' '),
    })
    all_data[-1].update(scores1)
    all_data[-1].update(scores2)

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
df.to_csv('data.csv')
print(df)
```

Saves `data.csv`:

[image]

---

EDIT: To add Odd, Prob columns for both players:

```
import requests 
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'http://www.tennisprediction.com/?year=2020&month=9&day=14'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

all_data = []
for t in soup.select('.main_time'):
    p1 = t.find_next(class_='main_player')
    p2 = p1.find_next(class_='main_player')
    tour = t.find_previous(id='main_tour')
    odd1 = t.find_next(class_='main_odds_m')
    odd2 = t.parent.find_next_sibling().find_next(class_='main_odds_m')
    prob1 = t.find_next(class_='main_perc')
    prob2 = t.parent.find_next_sibling().find_next(class_='main_perc')
    scores1 = {'player_1_set{}'.format(i): s for i, s in enumerate((tag.get_text(strip=True) for tag in t.parent.select('.main_res')), 1)}
    scores2 = {'player_2_set{}'.format(i): s for i, s in enumerate((tag.get_text(strip=True) for tag in t.parent.find_next_sibling().select('.main_res')), 1)}
    all_data.append({
        'tournament_name': ' / '.join( a.text for a in tour.select('a') ),
        'match_time': t.text,
        'player_1': p1.get_text(strip=True, separator=' '),
        'player_2': p2.get_text(strip=True, separator=' '),
        'odd1': odd1.text,
        'prob1': prob1.text,
        'odd2': odd2.text,
        'prob2': prob2.text
    })
    all_data[-1].update(scores1)
    all_data[-1].update(scores2)

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
df.to_csv('data.csv')
print(df)
```

Comment: we can add the odd column and the probability column?

Answer (score 1):

Andrej's solution is really nice and elegant. Accept his solution, but here was my go at it:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd



url = 'http://www.tennisprediction.com/?year=2020&month=9&day=14'
response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')


rows=[]
for matchClass in ['match','match1']:
    matches = soup.find_all('tr',{'class':'match'})
    for idx, match in enumerate(matches):
        if idx%2 != 0:
            continue
        row = {}
        tourny = match.find_previous('td',{'id':'main_tour'}).text
        time = match.find('td',{'class':'main_time'}).text
        p1 = match.find('td',{'class':'main_player'})
        player_1 = p1.text
        row.update({'tournament_name':tourny,'match_time':time,'player_1':player_1})
        
        sets = p1.find_previous('tr',{'class':'match'}).find_all('td',{'class':'main_res'})
        for idx,each_set in enumerate(sets):
            row.update({'p1_set%d'%(idx+1):each_set.text})
            
        p2 = match.find_next('td',{'class':'main_player'})
        player_2 = p2.text
        row.update({'player_2':player_2})
        sets = p2.find_next('tr',{'class':'match'}).find_all('td',{'class':'main_res'})
        for idx,each_set in enumerate(sets):
            row.update({'p2_set%d'%(idx+1):each_set.text})
        rows.append(row)
     
df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
```

**Output:**

```
print(df.head(10).to_string())
                                    tournament_name match_time                                player_1 p1_set1 p1_set2 p1_set3 p1_set4 p1_set5                                player_2 p2_set1 p2_set2 p2_set3 p2_set4 p2_set5
0        Roma / Italy prize / money : 5791 000 USD       11:10          Krajinovic Filip (SRB)   (26)        6       7                                  Krajinovic Filip (SRB)   (26)        4       5                        
1        Roma / Italy prize / money : 5791 000 USD       13:15           Dimitrov Grigor (BGR)   (20)        7       6                                   Dimitrov Grigor (BGR)   (20)        5       1                        
2        Roma / Italy prize / money : 5791 000 USD       13:50               Coric Borna (HRV)   (32)        6       6                                       Coric Borna (HRV)   (32)        4       4                        
3        Roma / Italy prize / money : 5791 000 USD       15:30               Humbert Ugo (FRA)   (42)        6       7                                       Humbert Ugo (FRA)   (42)        3   6 (5)                        
4        Roma / Italy prize / money : 5791 000 USD       19:00             Nishikori Kei (JPN)   (34)        6       7                                     Nishikori Kei (JPN)   (34)        4   6 (3)                        
5        Roma / Italy prize / money : 5791 000 USD       22:00         Travaglia Stefano (ITA)   (87)        6       7                                 Travaglia Stefano (ITA)   (87)        4   6 (4)                        
6  Iasi (IX) / Romania prize / money : 100 000 USD       10:05             Menezes Joao (BRA)   (189)        6       6                                     Menezes Joao (BRA)   (189)        4       4                        
7  Iasi (IX) / Romania prize / money : 100 000 USD       12:05             Cretu Cezar (2001) (ROU)          2       6       6                             Cretu Cezar (2001) (ROU)          6       3       4                
8  Iasi (IX) / Romania prize / money : 100 000 USD       14:35               Zuk Kacper (POL)   (306)        6       6                                       Zuk Kacper (POL)   (306)        2       0                        
9        Roma / Italy prize / money : 3452 000 USD       11:05  Pavlyuchenkova Anastasia (RUS)   (32)        6       6       6                  Pavlyuchenkova Anastasia (RUS)   (32)        4   7 (5)       1
```

Comment: we can add the odd column and the probability column?